# Donot wrap exceptions of Feign client Fall back method with Hystrix RunTime Exception

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

Fallback service is wrapping ProductNotFoundException into HystrixRunTimeException.
I want to propagate custom exception as it is instead of wrapping into HystrixRunTimeException.
Below is the code snippet for reference:

```
@FeignClient(name = "service1", fallback = FallBackService1.class )
public interface FeignService1{
      String validateProducts(Product product);
}

class FallBackService1 implements FeignService1{
  @override
  public String validateProducts(Product product){
     throw new ProductNotFoundException("P119","Product not found");
  }
}
```

I have enabled
feign.hystrix.enable = true.

Please help with this. I want to propagate the exception as it is. I do not want it to be wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks impossible to tell hystrix to not wrap your custom exception in the fallback method.
What you can do is to create your custom ErrorDecoder and throw your custom exception from there. In this case, your custom exception should implement `com.netflix.hystrix.exception.ExceptionNotWrappedByHystrix`
otherwise hystrix will wrap it into `HystrixRuntimeException`.

Simple example.

1. Create feign config with ErrorDecoder implementation. Note do not mark FeignClient1Config with the @Configuration annotation if you don't want all FeignClient to be processed by the same decoder.

```
import feign.codec.ErrorDecoder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class FeignClient1Config {

    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder customErrorDecoder() {
        return (methodKey, response) -> {
            throw new ProductNotFoundException("P119","Product not found for request " + response.request());
        };
    }
}
```

2. Your feign client should look like this

```
@FeignClient(name = "service1", configuration = FeignClient1Config.class)
public interface FeignService1{
      String validateProducts(Product product);
}
```

The drawback of this implementation is that all methods in the FeignService1 will be processed by the same error decoder.

To overcome it you can create your own fallbackFactory and add it as a property to the `@FeignClient(fallbackFactory = ...)`
Or the solution I like the most is [this](https://arnoldgalovics.com/maintainable-error-handling-with-feign-clients-not-a-dream-anymore/)
And do not forget your exception to implement ExceptionNotWrappedByHystrix class.